# Take results from one sheet and move them into many other sheets

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I have looked at similar answers to this question, but whatever I do I cannot get them to do what I need.

I have a daily email which has a CSV file giving call stats for our Sales team for the previous day.  What I need is to put them into Excel to give trending and historical call activity for the year.  Without VBA or Macros this is a very time consuming process.

The stats it gives are number of calls, and average call length (that are of any importance)  I have already got VBA to calculate the total outgoing with this:

```
Dim Call_Number As Integer
Dim Call_Time As Date
Dim Call_Total As Date

Call_Number = .Cells(2, 6).Value
Call_Time = .Cells(2, 7).Value

Call_Total = Call_Number * Call_Time
.Cells(12, 7).Value = Call_Total
```

So what I need is to take the 3 cells for each sales member, and move them into the right place in their relative sheets, which are separated by name.  I also need it to move into the next cell to the right if the destination cell is full, so I'm thinking I need to start the pasting process as Jan 1st and keep moving to the right until it finds blank cells.  Is there a way this can be done either in a button or automatically?

I have the first sheet used as the data import sheet, where we just import the data into csv, and because its standard formatting, every day it will give it all in the right formatting.

Code I have so far.  It doesn't error, but doesn't do anything:

```
Sub Move_Data()

Dim Dean As Worksheet
Dim Chris As Worksheet
Dim Paul As Worksheet
Dim Nigel As Worksheet
Dim Calc As Worksheet
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim J As Long
Dim i As Long


Set Dean = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DEAN 822")
Set Chris = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CHRIS 829")
Set Paul = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PAULP 830")
Set Nigel = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("NIGEL 833")
Set RUSSELL = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RUSSELL 835")
Set Calc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Calculation Sheet")

Lastrow = Range("C" & Dean.Columns.Count).End(xlToRight).Column

J = 2

For i = 0 To Lastrow

Set Rng = Dean.Range("C5").Offset(i, 0)
If Not (IsNull(Rng) Or IsEmpty(Rng)) Then
Calc.Cells(2, 4).Copy
Dean.Range("c" & J).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
J = J + 1
End If
Next i
Application.CutCopyMode = False


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
Lastrow = Range("C" & Dean.Columns.Count).End(xlToRight).Column
```

I think you want

```
Lastrow = Range("C" & Dean.Columns.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

---

"I also need ... in a button or automatically?"

```
LastCol = WshtName.Cells(CrntRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

will set `LastCol` to the last used column in row CrntRow.

---

```
J = 2

For i = 0 To Lastrow

  Set Rng = Dean.Range("C5").Offset(i, 0)
  If Not (IsNull(Rng) Or IsEmpty(Rng)) Then
    Calc.Cells(2, 4).Copy
    Dean.Range("c" & J).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    J = J + 1
  End If
Next i
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

I am not sure what this code is attempting.

It sets `Rng` to C5, C6, C7, C8, ... to Cn where n is Lastrow+5.  If C5, for example, if empty it copies C2 to `Calc.Cells(2, 4).

Did you mean to copy column C from worksheet Dean to column B of worksheet Calc?

If the removal of empty cells is not important then this will be faster and clearer:

```
Set Rng = Dean.Range(.Cells(5 ,"C"), .Cells(Lastrow ,"C"))
Rng.Copy Destination:=Calc.Cells(2, 4)
```

**New information in response to comment**

I cannot visualise either your source data or your destination data from your description so cannot give any specific advice.

Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I believe this is a good place to find previously posted information and a good place to post new questions but you must follow the site rules.

Right of centre in the top bar is the Help button.  Click this and read how to use this site.  Learn how to post a question that will be classified as a good question and will be answered quickly and helpfully.

I believe the biggest three problems with your question are:

- You ask too much.  You can ask as many good questions as you wish but there should only be one issue per question.
- You ask for information that is already available.
- You are too vague about your requirement to permit anyone to help.  You say you want to move three values per staff member.  But you do not show how either the worksheet “Calculation Sheet” or the staff member worksheets are arranged.  You cannot post images until you have a higher reputation but you can use the code facility to create “drawings” of the worksheets.

To avoid asking too much, you must break your requirement into small steps.  The following is my attempt to identify the necessary small steps based on my guess of what you seek.

The CSV files containing staff detail arrive as attachments to a daily email.  Are you manually saving those attachment?  An Outlook VBA macro to save an attachment would not be difficult to write.  I suggest you leave this for later but if you search Stack Overflow for “[outlook-vba] Save attachment” you will find relevant code.

The above shows how I search Stack Overflow.  I start with the tag for the language and follow it with some key words or a key phrase.  Sometimes it takes me a few goes to get the right search term but I rarely fail to find something interesting

How are you importing the CSV to Excel?  Are you doing this manually?  There are many possible VBA approaches.   Try searching for “[excel-vba] xxxx” where xxxx describes your preferred approach.

I assume the structure of the CSV file is pretty simple and there is no difficulty in find information in the individual rows.  You appear to know the easiest technique for finding the last row so you should have no difficulty in creating a loop that works down the rows.

How do you relate the staff member’s name in the CSV file with the name of their worksheet?  In your question you have worksheet names such as "DEAN 822", "CHRIS 829" and "PAULP 830".  Are these the names used in the CSV file?  What happens when a new staff member joins?  I doubt this happens very often but you do not want to be amending your macro when it does happen.

I do not understand your requirement for the new data to be added to the right of any existing data.  There will be three values per day so with around 200 working days per year that gives 600 columns.  To me that sees an awkward arrangement.  I would have thought one row per day would have been more convenient.

How will you run the macro?  You mention a button or automatically.  I do not like buttons since I find the tool bars cluttered enough already.  I prefer to use shortcut keys such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd>.  I rarely have more than one macro per workbook of this type so that works well for me.  By automatically, I assume you mean the macro will run automatically when the workbook is open.  I would start with the shortcut key but when you are ready look up “Events” and “Event routines”.  You will find an explanation of how you can have a macro start automatically when the workbook opens.

I hope the above is of some help.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late reply, only just had time to work on this issue again.  To answer your questions: Did you mean to copy column C from worksheet Dean to column B of worksheet Calc? No, it should be the other way round.

Comment: Let me clarify my requirement.  I need to automatically move specific data to the next available cell to the right.  If the source of the "Calculation Sheet" in C2-6 doesnt equal the right name, then no data should get entered.  This is to allow flexibility when staff members make no calls for that particular day.  Does that make sense?